# Is it possible to deconstruct this in only one operation?

Tags: javascript

I have an object `o` which I want to desconstruct into pieces `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. For now I am using three operations. I wonder if it can be done in one operation.

```js
const o = {
  a: {
    b: "b-value",
    c: {
      d: "d-value"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I did it in three operations (could it be done in only one?):

```js
const { a } = o
const { b, c } = a
const { d } = c
```

Display the output:

```js
console.log( {a,b,c,d} )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in a single operation

```
const { a, a: { b, c, c: { d } } } = o;
```

which outputs all four variables a, b, c and d

```
a = {b: 'b-value', c: {d: 'd-value'}}
b = 'b-value'
c = {d: 'd-value'}
d = 'd-value'
```

Answer (score 0):

in one operation:

```js
const o = {
  a: {
    b: "b-value",
    c: {
      d: "d-value"
    }
  }
}
const {a: {b, c: {d}}} = o;


console.log('{b, d}', {b, d});
```

Comment: This doesn't obtain `a` or `c` though, which seems to be what OP is after.